# How to pass a variable view to controller using JavaScript function using URL::action method in laravel 4.2

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-4

The choice value is assigned from a dropdownlist.That value is passing to javascript myFunction as a parameter. And i want to create a table in view using data in database. The code works fine and creates table  when im not passing a parameter. But i want to pass a parameter.Help me here guys.

**This is my code in view**

```
 function myFunction($choice) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + $choice;

    $.get("{{ URL::action('CombinationController@readData',array('choice'=> 'choice'))}}", function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, value) {
            var tr = $("<tr/>");
            tr.append($("<td/>", {
                text: value.student_id
            })).append($("<td/>", {
                text: value.initials + " " + value.last_name
            })).append($("<input />", {
                type: 'checkbox', value: value.student_id
            }))

            $('#student').append(tr);
        });
    });
}
```

**This is code in Route**

```
 Route::get('readData/{choice}','CombinationController@readData');
```

**This is my CombinationController**

```
public function readData($choice)
{
    if($choice==0) {
        $StuPS1ch1 = CombinationSubmits::join('student', 'combination_submits.student_id', '=', 'student.student_id')
    ->select('combination_submits.student_id', 'student.initials', 'student.last_name')
    ->where(['choice_1' => 'PS1'])
    ->get();
    }
    return $StuPS1ch1;
}
```

Comment: is it in angular js or angular 5

Answer (score 0):

When your view is rendered, php has already finished compilind all the code. By the time your javascript function runs (client side), your URL (generated by PHP on the server side) is already a string, so you won't have the effect you want.

If you try to generate a url with dinamic segments, like this:

```
URL::action('CombinationController@readData',array('choice'=> $choice))
```

You'll probably get an error, because PHP's URL facade requires the $choice variable to be available on render.

I sugest changing the variable to a query string, so you can do something like this:

```
function myFunction(choice) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + choice;

    $.get("{{ URL::action('CombinationController@readData') }}?choice=" + choice, function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, value) {
            var tr = $("<tr/>");
            tr.append($("<td/>", {
                text: value.student_id
            })).append($("<td/>", {
                text: value.initials + " " + value.last_name
            })).append($("<input />", {
                type: 'checkbox', value: value.student_id
            }));

            $('#student').append(tr);
        });
    });
}
```

Also you'll have to change your controller:

```
public function readData()
{
    $choice = \Request::input('choice');
    if($choice==0) {
        $StuPS1ch1 = CombinationSubmits::join('student', 'combination_submits.student_id', '=', 'student.student_id')
    ->select('combination_submits.student_id', 'student.initials', 'student.last_name')
    ->where(['choice_1' => 'PS1'])
    ->get();
    }
    return $StuPS1ch1;
}
```

Comment: Arthur Samarcos, There is a error in curly brackets in your answer.I couldn't identify it.can you correct  it.Thank you

Comment: The have changed the code according to ur code. bt its not working. could you explain the all changes that i should done in the code

Comment: What exactly is not working. Please give some details.

Comment: The value for choice is assigning when selecting the dropdown list. Though that value is printing in demo,the table is not creating. should i change the code in controller as well as route file.

Comment: @wow Yeah, now you'll not receive $choice as a url segment, but you can use the request facade.